# The status of Jupyter extension is "installing" forever

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have been using vscode + Jupyter without any problem for a year. Several weeks ago, suddenly I could not run my notebooks as it always said "Install kernels from the market" instead of listing the available kernels. In the meanwhile, the status of Jupyter extension became "installing". However, python worked well in prompt. Just the vscode + Jupyter combination stopped working.

So I completely removed vscode and all the extensions in the .vscode folder and reinstalled vscode. Then when I installed the Jupyter extension, it got stuck at "installing" forever, even though the other extensions were installed successfully (python and Jupyter Keymap + Notebook Renderers).

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI2Pm.png)

I am behind a proxy, but given the other extensions can be installed without problem, I don't know whether this is the cause.

Here are some information:

VS code:
Version: 1.67.2 (user setup)
Commit: c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
Date: 2022-05-17T18:15:52.058Z
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Jupyter extension:
v2022.4.1021342353
Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: You can try installing the [pre-release](https://imgur.com/a/OSSLwlW) version of jupyter-notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It does not work though. The installation still gets stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions that might help you:

**Set up Internet proxy:**

Click "File - Preferences - Settings" in the menu bar, then expand "Applications" in "User Settings", select "Proxy" and enter the proxy address and port.

[image]

**Install via offline package:**

Click view->Extensions in the menu bar. Find the icon `...` in the upper right corner of the pop-up Extensions (shortcut Ctrl+Shift+X) window, and click to select "install from VSIX...".

[image]

Import the newly downloaded extension package into the local file. After installation, "Completed installing *** extension from VSIX" will be displayed in the lower right corner. Restart VSCode to take effect.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! 

I tried the offline package, downloaded from https://www.vsixhub.com/vsix/89680/. When I tried to install from the .vsix file, strangely, it also got stuck half way (with a clock sign beside the extension icon). Same as installation from extension market, It did generate a temporary folder at .vscode\extensions\, but keep like it forever without changing the name to "ms-something". 

So I guess the problem lies in installation instead of downloading. But still puzzled why and how to fix it.

Comment: OK, here's another way. That is installing the extension via the [command line](https://imgur.com/a/AQpO8KW).
Please open a command line window under the `bin` folder in your VS Code installation directory. Execute the following command:
`code --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter`

Comment: Great to learn that there are so many ways to install extensions in vscode. However, this way leads to similar result: It looks identical to your screenshot, except the last line which marks the success of installation. The installation seems to stop in the half way again. A temporary folder was generated at .vscode\extensions\, but kept being temporary. I was wondering what problem can cause an interruption during installation.

Comment: Can you provide your installation information. The reason for the installation failure may be that the previous installation was not cleanly removed, or that jupyter (not the jupyter extension) was not installed successfully.
Another possible reason is that it has been installed, but the state has not changed.
Of course, at present, I think your problem may be a problem with the machine. Since I can't reproduce your problem, you can file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) for tracking.